# Nested ngFor with select and form

Tags: javascript, angular, html, forms, typescript

I have to create a security question and answer template for my website. Which helps user in forgot password. General case as all websites have

In my case I will get json object which has question_id and question.
I need to give a drop down to select to select questions and user will select one and answer for that question.

If the user user selects same question again it should show error.
User should answer 5 questions, as I have given five input boxes.
After filling all the details he should submit form else have to keep on showing user error.

Could you please help me how to do it.

I tried putting nested loop it doesn’t help me much in validating all the required elements.

Please give me a temple to do it. I am breaking my head from past 1 day.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the validators, they can give you a good hand at this.